# Error receiving emails through email router "#9628...VerifyCommitted - Transaction has not been committed"

Tags: dynamics-crm

Started yesterday. No recent change on configuration. It happens with MOST but not all emails received. While troubleshooting noticed that if its a plain text email it goes through, but if it's an html email with an image it will give me the error below:

> 08/26/2014 04:46:44 : #9628 - An error occurred while delivering the email message with subject "EMAIL SUBJECT HERE" in mailbox myname@mydomain.com for delivery to https://disco.crm.dynamics.com/myorg. System.ServiceModel.FaultException`1[Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.OrganizationServiceFault]: VerifyCommitted - Transaction has not been committed (Fault Detail is equal to Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.OrganizationServiceFault).

Any idea on how to get it resolved?

Comment: -1? Really? Not even a comment or suggestion? Come on...

Comment: The same way it started, it went away. Today all income emails are being processed without problems. I opened a support ticket 2 days ago but don't think it has anything to do with this change in behavior. Haven't received a response from the support team but as I do I will post it here.

Comment: According to Microsoft Support there was an issue (bug) on the crm server and a patch was applied on 08/26 to fix it. Haven't seen the error since.